# basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) VS $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) WITH Header("Location: ")

Tags: php

Im attempting to build a simple solution in php to prevent form re-submission on any POST forms on any website where a user may refresh the page after a form has initially been submitted.

Ive come up with the following script:

```
//STORE POST DATA TO A SESSION  
if($_POST){
    $_SESSION['reserved']['post'] = $_POST;
    header("Location: " . basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    exit();
}

//REFILL $_POST
if(isset($_SESSION['reserved']['post'])){
    $_POST = $_SESSION['reserved']['post'];
    unset($_SESSION['reserved']['post']);
}

//HANDLE DATA AS USUAL...
if($_POST){
    echo $_POST['firstname'];
}
```

Locally testing a project my current URL is 
http://localhost/system/CustomersV2/account.php?action=register

My question relates to line 4 of the script.

Which is a more widely accepted/compatible method of redirecting a page to itsself irregardless of webhost or web browser?

```
//redirect to 'account.php?action=register'
header("Location: " . basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

or

```
//redirects to '/system/CustomersV2/account.php?action=register'
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Or does it really not matter? (Any other suggestions regarding this script are also very much welcomed)

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use `header()` redirect after you process your POST data from a form, a better way would be to use the [`HTTP 303` redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)